# Silence messages about masked functions

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to silence messages that explain that certain functions were masked by other packages. I have tried different combinations, but none delivered what I need.

The chunk I have is:

```
<<loadpkgs, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(doMC))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(aroma.affymetrix))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(crlmm))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(snpStats))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pd.genomewidesnp.6))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(GenomicRanges))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggbio))
@
```

But the output (which I hoped to be none) is (on the resulting PDF):

```
## Loading required package:  foreach
## foreach:  simple, scalable parallel programming from Revolution Analytics
## Use Revolution R for scalability, fault tolerance and more.
## http://www.revolutionanalytics.com
## Loading required package:  iterators
## Loading required package:  parallel
## Loading required package:  R.utils
## Loading required package:  R.oo
## Loading required package:  R.methodsS3
## R.methodsS3 v1.5.2 (2013-10-06) successfully loaded.  See ?R.methodsS3 for help.
## R.oo v1.15.8 (2013-10-10) successfully loaded.  See ?R.oo for help.
##
## Attaching package:  ’R.oo’
##
## The following objects are masked from ’package:methods’:
##
##    getClasses, getMethods
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: As knitr is an R package your question may get better exposure if you add the R tag.

Answer (score 12):

Setting the parameter `warn.conflicts=FALSE` in `library()` as in

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
```

should do the trick. This is particularly useful with parallel computing when potentially hundreds or more cores are loading the library.

Comment: Do these kinds of settings allow for "defaults" at the R session level? In that case the setting could be added to `.Rprofile`

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of the "Loading ..." messages use `quietly=TRUE` in the library call (and continue to use the suppressPackageStartupMessages):

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(gdata, quietly=TRUE))
```

If you want to make this more compact, perhaps:

```
pkgs <-c('gdata', 'doMC', 'aroma.affymetrix', 'crlmm', 'snpStats', 
         'pd.genomewidesnp.6', 'GenomicRanges','ggbio')
for(p in pkgs) suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(p, quietly=TRUE, 
                                                      character.only=TRUE))
```

Might be safer to do some sort of test if you are going to suppress the "loading messages".

```
for(p in pkgs) suppressPackageStartupMessages( stopifnot( 
                                               library(p, quietly=TRUE, 
                                                        logical.return=TRUE, 
                                                        character.only=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you, @DWin. That did address the "Loading..." message issue. But I still have the messages like: "The following object is masked by package: ...."... I understand the consequences of not showing these messages (strange behaviors of functions that were masked, etc), but I'd like to silence them as well.... Thoughts?

Comment: I suspect from the output that you show that the remaining messages are due to the code in the named packages that is `attach()`-ing unnamed packages. What I don't know, but perhaps @HenrikB knows, is whether it is possible to load those packages "manually" so that the attach() code "recognizes" that they do not need to be `attach()`ed.

Comment: There is no need to use `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` or `quietly=TRUE`, after you have used the chunk option `message=FALSE` and updated your R packages. One exception is some package authors do not use `packageStartupMessage()` to write package startup messages, e.g. they use `cat()` instead. In that case, you can still use `results='hide'`. BTW, `stopifnot()` here is not necessary, either, because `library()` will `stop()` if the package does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

`suppressPackageStartupMessages(library('packageName'))` and `library('packageName', quitely = TRUE)` will suppress all messages generated when loading a package, including such as "loading required package XYZ".

The question asks the slightly more restricted question of how to suppress the warnings about conflicts, which can be accomplished with `library('packageName', warn.conflicts = FALSE)`. R 3.6.0 introduces a global solution courtesy of the `conflicts.policy` option:

```
options(conflicts.policy = list(warn = FALSE))
library('packageName')
```

This policy risks hiding unexpected warnings alongside expected warnings, so it's safer to explicitly specify anticipated conflicts and use `options(conflicts.policy = 'strict')` [which is shorthand for `options(conflicts.policy = list(error = TRUE, warn = FALSE))`].

Anticipated conflicts can be listed using the `mask.ok` parameter to `library`:

```r
# 'packageName' may mask any function named 'foo' and 'bar':
library('packageName', mask.ok = c('foo', 'bar'))

# 'packageName' may mask any function in the package 'base':
library('packageName', mask.ok = list(base = TRUE))

# 'packageName' may mask only the 'base' functions 'foo' and 'bar':
library('packageName', mask.ok = list(base = c('foo', 'bar')))
```

We still have a problem if package A loads package B that masks a function in package C, as seems to occur when `doMC` loads `R.oo` that masks `methods::getClasses`. We can solve this by setting 'conflict rules' for each package that will be loaded:

```
options(conflicts.policy = 'strict')
conflictRules('R.oo', 
              mask.ok = list(methods = c('getClasses', 'getMethods'))
library('doMC')
```

The conflictRules options could be specified in an `.Rprofile` file to save explicitly calling them each time a script is loaded.

More detail via Luke Tierney's ["Managing Search Path Conflicts"](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/03/19/managing-search-path-conflicts/index.html).

Comment: Does this still work in R 4.0+? I cannot seem to make this work (cf https://stackoverflow.com/q/72827802/3888000). Also, didn't you swap `mask.ok` (in library) and `can.mask` (in options) in your answer?

Comment: I've corrected the parameter name, thanks for spotting. This should still work in R4.0+, AFAIK – is it not working for you?

Comment: No, it is not, unfortunately. See my other post in the link for more details, I find it very weird that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled that you see those message for the R.* packages.  The following:

`suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(aroma.affymetrix))`

should be silent (except warnings on masked objects).  If you try outside knitr, do you still see those messages?

/Henrik
(author of R.* and aroma.* packages)

Comment: I'm guessing from the output above that 'doMC' is attaching 'foreach` and the other packages with code that is not honoring any "quietly" request passed to 'doMC'.

Comment: Hi @HenrikB, the issue is not related to your packages in particular. This happens for many others (like Biobase, Matrix, etc) but it happened that yours were on top. The issue is that I'm trying to silence the warnings on masked objects... I even tried the uncommon:

suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg, quietly=TRUE))))

But the warnings (on masked objects) still appear...