# mask.ok in conflicts.policy option does not work

Tags: r

I load a dozen of packages when I work, mostly tidyverse, which I trust enough to manage their conflicts with base R.
Therefore, I would like to get rid of the expected conflict warnings when I load them.

As read in `?library` and understood in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384440/3888000 which is itself citing the official [R-blog](https://blog.r-project.org/2019/03/19/managing-search-path-conflicts/)), I tried to use the `mask.ok` argument, either in `library()` or in `options()`.

However, this does not seem to work as intended:

```r
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")

options(conflicts.policy="depends.ok")
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I also tried a lot of other options with no more success. Here is a testing code that unload and reload `lubridate` with different settings. It can run but the warnings remain.

```r
f = function(mask.ok=NULL){
  detach("package:lubridate", unload=TRUE)
  if(is.null(mask.ok)) library(lubridate)
  else library(lubridate, mask.ok=x)
}
f("base")
f(list(base=TRUE))
options(conflicts.policy=list(can.mask="base"))
f()
options(conflicts.policy=list(can.mask=list(base=TRUE)))
f()
conflictRules("lubridate", mask.ok="base")
f()

options(conflicts.policy = list(error = TRUE,
                                generics.ok = TRUE,
                                can.mask = c("base", "methods", "utils",
                                             "grDevices", "graphics",
                                             "stats"),
                                depends.ok = TRUE))
f()
```

Only this works, but I guess it will muffle the unexpected warnings as well:

```r
detach("package:lubridate", unload=TRUE)
options(conflicts.policy=list(warn=FALSE))
library(lubridate)
```

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I've replicated this in my environment... it certainly seems to differ from the documented behaviour.  Worth registering as a bug with R?

Comment: Reporting bugs in base R is quite painful but I guess this is worth trying. If you could replicate, it definitely seems like a bug/regression.

Comment: @MartinSmith I tried with R3.6.1 and the bug is still there, did you manage to get it working on R3.6.0 back when you wrote your answer?